# Calculate time difference in minutes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, difference

I need the time difference between two times in minutes. I am having the start time and end time as shown below:

```
start time | End Time    
11:15:00   | 13:15:00    
10:45:00   | 18:59:00
```

I need the output for first row as 45,60,15 which corresponds to the time difference between 11:15 and 12:00, 12:00 and 13:00, 13:00 and 13:15 respectively.

Comment: can you please post the output what you want ??

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I need the output for first row of data as 45,60,15. Its enough to print the values as separate columns.

Comment: what is desired output for second row

Comment: For 2nd row, I need the output as 15, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 59

Comment: How many columns that is needed//

Comment: I need 24 Columns. The value can be 0 if its not applicable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following works as expected:

```
SELECT  Diff = CASE DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartTime, EndTime)
                    WHEN 0 THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime) AS VARCHAR(10))
                    ELSE CAST(60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, StartTime) AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                        REPLICATE(',60', DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartTime, EndTime) - 1) + 
                        + ',' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, EndTime) AS VARCHAR(10))
                END
FROM    (VALUES 
            (CAST('11:15' AS TIME), CAST('13:15' AS TIME)),
            (CAST('10:45' AS TIME), CAST('18:59' AS TIME)),
            (CAST('10:45' AS TIME), CAST('11:59' AS TIME))
        ) t (StartTime, EndTime);
```

To get 24 columns, you could use 24 case expressions, something like:

```
SELECT  [0] = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartTime, EndTime) = 0
                        THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime)
                    ELSE 60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, StartTime)
                END,
        [1] = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartTime, EndTime) = 1 
                        THEN DATEPART(MINUTE, EndTime)
                    WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartTime, EndTime) > 1 THEN 60
                END,
        [2] = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartTime, EndTime) = 2
                        THEN DATEPART(MINUTE, EndTime)
                    WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartTime, EndTime) > 2 THEN 60
                END -- ETC
FROM    (VALUES 
            (CAST('11:15' AS TIME), CAST('13:15' AS TIME)),
            (CAST('10:45' AS TIME), CAST('18:59' AS TIME)),
            (CAST('10:45' AS TIME), CAST('11:59' AS TIME))
        ) t (StartTime, EndTime);
```

The following also works, and may end up shorter than repeating the same case expression over and over:

```
WITH Numbers (Number) AS
(   SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.N) - 1
    FROM    (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) AS t1 (N)
            CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1)) AS t2 (N)
), YourData AS
(   SELECT  StartTime, EndTime
    FROM    (VALUES 
                (CAST('11:15' AS TIME), CAST('13:15' AS TIME)),
                (CAST('09:45' AS TIME), CAST('18:59' AS TIME)),
                (CAST('10:45' AS TIME), CAST('11:59' AS TIME))
            ) AS t (StartTime, EndTime)
), PivotData AS
(   SELECT  t.StartTime,
            t.EndTime,
            n.Number,
            MinuteDiff = CASE WHEN n.Number = 0 AND DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartTime, EndTime) = 0 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime)
                                WHEN n.Number = 0 THEN 60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, StartTime)
                                WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, t.StartTime, t.EndTime) <= n.Number THEN DATEPART(MINUTE, EndTime)
                                ELSE 60
                            END
    FROM    YourData AS t
            INNER JOIN Numbers AS n
                ON n.Number <= DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartTime, EndTime)
)
SELECT  *
FROM    PivotData AS d
        PIVOT 
        (   MAX(MinuteDiff)
            FOR Number IN 
            (   [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], 
                [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11],
                [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], 
                [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23]
            ) 
        ) AS pvt;
```

It works by joining to a table of 24 numbers, so the case expression doesn't need to be repeated, then rolling these 24 numbers back up into columns using `PIVOT`

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks. Suppose if I need 24 columns and I need to have the value as 0 if not applicable, how to achieve it?

Comment: Results in null in edge cases. example '23:55', '00:05'

Comment: @pkExec There was a slight issue with the PIVOT solution, but I think the "edge" case you refer to isn't an edge case, it is just that none of the solutions above are designed to deal with a start time that is after the end time.

Comment: @GarethD except that it actually isn't necessarily 'after'. Depending on the actual problem, the time pairs may refer to e.g. a timetable, implying "Day1-23:55", "Day2-00:05". That's why I refer to it as an edge case, depends on the problem. imo, there should be a check to add +1day before the datediff operation if enddate<startdate. In any case, your solution is perfect for the op, just mentioning it in case anyone blindly copies/pastes it.

Answer (score 74):

Use [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) with MINUTE difference:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '11:10:10' , '11:20:00') AS MinuteDiff
```

Query that may help you:

```
SELECT StartTime, EndTime, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime , EndTime) AS MinuteDiff 
FROM TableName
```

Comment: `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF' `
According to the documentation for MariaDB DATEDIFF only takes two arguments:

Comment: @TarangP  the question relates to SQL Server not MariaDB

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the DATEDIFF you can also use the TIMEDIFF function or the TIMESTAMPDIFF.

EXAMPLE

```
SET @date1 = '2010-10-11 12:15:35', @date2 = '2010-10-10 00:00:00';

SELECT 
TIMEDIFF(@date1, @date2) AS 'TIMEDIFF',
TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, @date1, @date2) AS 'Hours',
TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, @date1, @date2) AS 'Minutes',
TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, @date1, @date2) AS 'Seconds';
```

RESULTS

```
TIMEDIFF : 36:15:35
Hours : -36
Minutes : -2175
Seconds : -130535
```

Comment: TIMEDIFF and TIMESTAMPDIFF are not functions in SQL Server. This does work in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEDIFF(it is a built-in function) and % (for scale calculation) and CONCAT for make result to only one column

```
select CONCAT('Month: ',MonthDiff,' Days: ' , DayDiff,' Minutes: ',MinuteDiff,' Seconds: ',SecondDiff) as T  from 
(SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2017-10-15 19:39:47' , '2017-12-31 23:59:59') % 12 as MonthDiff,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, '2017-10-15 19:39:47' , '2017-12-31 23:59:59') % 30 as DayDiff,
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, '2017-10-15 19:39:47' , '2017-12-31 23:59:59') % 24 as HourDiff,
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2017-10-15 19:39:47' , '2017-12-31 23:59:59') % 60 AS MinuteDiff,
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2017-10-15 19:39:47' , '2017-12-31 23:59:59') % 60 AS SecondDiff) tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below to get the time difference in hh:mm:ss format

**Select StartTime, EndTime, CAST((EndTime - StartTime) as time(0)) 'TotalTime' from [TableName]**

Answer (score -2):

Try this..

```
select starttime,endtime, case
  when DATEDIFF(minute,starttime,endtime) < 60  then DATEDIFF(minute,starttime,endtime) 
  when DATEDIFF(minute,starttime,endtime) >= 60
  then '60,'+ cast( (cast(DATEDIFF(minute,starttime,endtime) as int )-60) as nvarchar(50) )
end from TestTable123416
```

All You need is [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189794.aspx)..