# Difference in minutes between sign-in and sign-out per user_id

Tags: sql-server, datetime

How can I find the time difference between sign_in `date_time` and sign_out or last operation that user_id did, `date_time` per `user_id` for each instance of `authentications = 'sign_in'`? If a sign out is not present or another sign in occurs without signing out, then consider the last command of that `user_id`.

```
user_id date_time               authentications
2224    2015-09-22 06:04:00.467 sign in
2224    2015-09-22 06:10:00.467 shift_9_command
2224    2015-09-22 06:12:00.467 sign out
2224    2015-09-22 06:18:00.467 sign in
2224    2015-09-22 06:27:00.467 page_1_searching
2214    2015-09-21 06:30:00.467 sign in
2214    2015-09-21 06:37:00.467 page_1_searching
2214    2015-09-21 06:39:00.467 page_1_searching
2214    2015-09-21 07:04:00.467 page_1_searching
2254    2015-09-21 07:15:00.467 sign in
2264    2015-09-21 07:16:00.467 sign in
1224    2015-09-29 06:04:00.467 sign in
1224    2015-09-29 06:10:00.467 operation_1
1224    2015-09-29 06:12:00.467 operation_2
1224    2015-09-29 06:18:00.467 operation_3
1224    2015-09-29 06:27:00.463 operation_4
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate time difference in minutes in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991807/calculate-time-difference-in-minutes-in-sql-server)

Comment: use DATEDIFF Function

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DATEDIFF` function, with `ss` as the interval, to get the difference in seconds.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx for the full documentation, along with a number of samples.

Your question is much larger than the title implies, unfortunately I don't have time to solve the whole issue for you.

---

Apologies, you said minutes not seconds.  The interval for minutes in DATEDIFF is `mi` or `n`.

Comment: Thank you.. for your reply but  if sign out is not there for sign in then i want last operation as sign out for that user_id

Answer (score 0):

I had to take some liberties to fully choose the logic, but this may work for you:

```
SELECT
   I.user_id,
   SignInTime = I.date_time,
   SignOutTime = O.date_time,
   SignedInDurationMinutes = DateDiff(second, 0, O.date_time - I.date_time) / 60.0,
   ActualSignOutAction = O.authentications
FROM
   dbo.UserActions I
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM dbo.UserActions O
      WHERE
         I.user_id = O.user_id
         AND I.date_time < O.date_time
      ORDER BY
         CASE
            WHEN O.authentications IN ('sign_in', 'sign_out') THEN date_time
            ELSE '99991231'
         END,
         CASE
            WHEN O.authentications IN ('sign_in', 'sign_out') THEN '16000101'
            ELSE O.date_time
         END DESC
   )
WHERE
   I.authentications = 'sign_in'
;
```

If two `sign_in` events occur without an intervening `sign_out`, I chose to take the next `sign_in` rather than the last action, for one thing because it made the query easier, and for another it was open to interpretation and could have gone either way. If this is not what you'd like, then please speak up.

I also assumed that you're using the `datetime` data type for the `date_time` column. If not, my raw subtraction of `O.date_time - I.date_time` may not work. Again, let me know, and I can update it.