# SQL Error. It only works before 12am

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SET @secret= - (convert(float,getdate()) - convert(int,getdate()) ) * 1000000 ;
```

WHen I put the `'-'` before the (convert, it works after 12 AM but when I delete the `'-'` it works before 12 AM. This is seriously strange. What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: If you want calculate time difference check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991807/calculate-time-difference-in-minutes-in-sql-server

Comment: When you say "it works" or doesn't, what do you mean? What is this trying to do?

Comment: Are you sure you mean before 12 am?

Comment: It's hard to explain in English but I'll give it a go. What I'm trying is to make a table with 9 columns. The information which goes in there are submitted by other people from an another application. The submitted infomration w ill go in to my table. Everything works good so far except for 1 thing. The table doesn't show on my webpage after 12 am because of the '-' before the convert. ANd I have seriously no idea how to solve this..

Comment: What you need to explain is what value you expect to be on `@secret` You are probably asking the wrong question [**What is the XY problem?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want this calculation:

```
select -1000000 * datediff(second, 0, cast(getdate() as time)) / (24*60*60.0)
```

I would suggest that you use this instead of your more arcane approach to convert fractions of a day to a large number.

Or, if you prefer more precision:

```
select -1000000 * datediff(millisecond, 0, cast(getdate() as time)) / (24*60*60*1000.0)
```

Comment: is one query missing?  You say something like `You want X. I suggest Y, but you may prefer Z`  But I only see X, Z ??

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza X is the first in this, Y is the one in the OP, Z is the second in this.