# Calculating time difference when times are cross midnight

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate the time difference where the times cross midnight.

> (Difference between 09:00pm and 01:00am)

Using Microsoft SQL, does not recognise datetrunc().

Code using at the moment is 
`datediff(minute, S.Start_, S.End_)/60`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate time difference in minutes in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991807/calculate-time-difference-in-minutes-in-sql-server)

Comment: You can use datediff itself. Why do you want to change it ?

Comment: use DATEDIFF as like `SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2019-05-14 21:00' , '2019-05-15 01:00') AS MinuteDiff` [for more reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: date part is required. otherwise if the end time is 10 PM next day, this will return 1 hr where as it should be 1Day(24 Hr) + 1 Hr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `case` expression:

```
(case when s.start_ < s.end_
      then datediff(hour, S.Start_, S.End_)
      else datediff(hour, S.End_, s.Start_)
 end)
```

Dividing the minutes by 60 and ignoring the remainder is the same as counting the hours.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to have both values as DateTime, then you can get the real value, as a workaround you can assume that if the end time is lower than the start time, means that it refers to next day, but it will be limited to 23 hours (24 if you use <=)

```
DECLARE @start TIME = '21:00'
DECLARE @end TIME = '01:00' 
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, @start , @end) + CASE WHEN @end < @start THEN 24 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
create function fn_MinuteDiff(@Start time, @End time)
returns int
as
begin
    if @End<@Start
    begin
        return 1440 - datediff(minute,@End, @Start) 
    end
    return datediff(minute, @Start, @End) 

end
```

then call it in your select statement

```
select dbo.fn_MinuteDiff (cast('9:00pm' as time), cast('1:00am' as time))
```